# Sed search&replace from CSV file inserts carriage return

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file `retimp_info.csv` with two columns and ~500 rows like this:

```
rettag, retid  
231,1
```

and a file `mdb_ret_exp.csv` with multiple rows and columns:

```
a,s,d,231,f,g
a,s,d,345,f,g
```

So the goal is to find and replace the occurrences of the `rettag` with `retid` from the first file. Now there are multiple `rettag`s that need to be replaced inside the `mdb_ret_exp.csv`. (using commas so the column can be specified incase that number occurs anywhere else i may not know about ie - different column).

Here's what I tried:

```
while IFS="," read -r rettag retid; do
  sed -i "s/,$rettag,/,$retid,/" mdb_ret_exp.csv
done < $HOME/retimp_info.csv
```

It almost works, but it adds an extra carriage return on every replacement:

```
a,s,d,1
,f,g
a,s,d,345,f,g
```

I expected it to still remain on one line:

```
a,s,d,1,f,g
a,s,d,345,f,g
```

How do I avoid the extra carriage return?

Comment: It looks like you'd be running `s/,231,,/,1,/` while you wanted `s/, 231,/, 1,/` (note difference in spaces and commas). Have you taken any steps to isolate the problem?

Comment: yes i solved that brief issue with my ifs > IFS mistake in a sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely caused by your `retimp_info.csv` having DOS/Windows style `\r\n` line endings. You could remove them from the file while reading:

```
cat "$HOME/retimp_info.csv" | tr -d '\r' | while IFS="," read -r rettag retid; do
  sed -i "s/,$rettag,/,$retid,/" mdb_ret_exp.csv
done
```

or strip them from the file in advance with `dos2unix` or by opening the file in a text editor, choosing "Unix line endings" or equivalent option, and then saving it again.

Comment: Use `tr … < "$HOME/retimp_info.csv"`; there's no need for the cat to be dragged in.

Answer (score 1):

You're barking up the wrong tree. Just do this:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in map) {
            $i = map[$i]
        }
    }
    print
}
' $HOME/retimp_info.csv mdb_ret_exp.csv
```

That will solve all of your current problems and the ones you may not have hit yet, but probably will, related to:

1. doing regexp instead of string comparisons, and
2. the fact your current approach can't work for the first or last
   fields on each line, and
3. as written your sed loop could replace the replacements after making them

In addition to being far more robust, the awk approach will also be at least an order of magnitude faster than your current approach. See also [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice).

Oh, and run `dos2unix` or similar on your input files first as they currently have Windows control-M line endings (use `cat -v file` to see them).

Answer (score -1):

Update: used the following -
`while IFS="," read -r rettag retid; do
  sed -i "s/,$rettag,/,$retid,/g" mdb_ret_exp.csv
done < $home/retimp_info.csv`

worked fine but now after it replaces the proper value (which resides in the middle of the line/row) it inserts a carriage return - causing the following information to be moved to the next row

ie:
a,s,d,231,f,g

now is -
a,s,d,1
,f,g
Need ,f,g to remain on the same line...

Comment: This should really be edited into the question as extra information.